# oas-raml-converter: env: can't execute 'node --harmony': No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, npm, raml

When executing `oas-raml-converter` tool, encountered this error on the Linux environment.

```
/usr/bin/env: node --harmony: No such file or directory
```

The same tool when run from Windows worked well. Though there are other questions on SO for similar problems, adding this because this was the simplest of the solutions I could get it working at the quickest, but was hard to find through Google.

Answer (score 0):

The solution / workaround is to replace `--harmony` is `converter.js`. The location of the same would be `node_modules/oas-raml-converter/lib/bin/converter.js` and the location of node_modules can be figured out using `npm root` for local installation type and `npm root -g` for global one. Once the directory location is figured out, execute the below command to get the `oas-raml-converter` working.

```
 sed -i "1s/ --harmony//" [PATH_TO_NODE_MODULES]/oas-raml-converter/lib/bin/converter.js
```

In CentOS when logged in with root, below were the directories:

```
[root@centos7 ~]# npm root
/root/node_modules
[root@centos7 ~]# npm root -g
/usr/lib/node_modules
```

[Source](https://github.com/mulesoft/oas-raml-converter/issues/33)